# Test the connection between docker containers within docker-composed environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, port

We are using docker-compose to set up the services for our app:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:11.1
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: xxx
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: xxx
      POSTGRES_DB: xxx
      PGPASSWORD: xxx
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./data/dbdump:/dbdump
    networks:
      - zenet
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  # The React web application
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: devenv/web/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src/client-app:/usr/local/abc
      - /usr/local/abc/node_modules
    networks:
      - zenet
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: npm run startindocker

  # The Django Rest Framework API
  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: devenv/api/Dockerfile
    environment:
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: abc.settings.dev
      PYTHONSTARTUP: /root/pythonstartup.sh
      PYTHONIOENCODING: UTF-8
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/local/borrow-a-boat
      - ./devenv/api/pythonrc.py:/root/pythonstartup.sh
    networks:
      - zenet
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    command:
      python3 /usr/local/borrow-a-boat/src/django/abc/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9000
    tty: true

volumes:
  pgdata:
  customboatdata:

networks:
  zenet:
```

(sensitive info has been replaced)

My colleagues have the setup running fine. I setup the app & the volumes & containers are up & running. I can hit the service `api` at port 9000 fine from browser & confirm that the db is populated. However, my `web` service is unable to get the data from the api. <s>How can I confirm that the above assertion is correct & that the web really cannot communicate with the api service.</s>

And how can I fix this & get the web to receive the data from api. Apologies for the newbie question.

EDIT:

When I run `ping api` from within the `web` container using `docker exec -it [containerID] /bin/sh`, I am recieving a response in the form of :

`64 bytes from 172.18.0.4: seq=139 ttl=64 time=0.084 ms`

So, clearly, my assertion is incorrect. Why is `web` service unable to get a response from `api` service. When I load the `web` app in browser, I do not get any log display in the terminal of the api being hit.

EDIT-2 :

As per @runwuf question & my response, clearly, the 'web' is able to communicate with the 'api' service. So, something else is wrong. Here are the steps, we follow to setup the stack on our systems. I use a Linux Mint 19.2 OS, while the team uses Macs. The commands are:

- docker kill $(docker_container_names)
- docker rm -v $(docker_container_names)
- docker volume rm abc_pgdata
- docker image rm abc_api
- docker image rm abc_web
- docker-compose build
- docker-compose up -d db api web
- ssh abc@abc.com 'pg_dump abc | gzip' | gunzip | docker-compose run --rm db psql --host db --username abc
- docker-compose run --rm db psql --host db --username abc -c "update core_photo set image_base = 'sample.jpg'"
- docker-compose run --rm db psql --host db --username abc -c "update core_experienceimage set image_base = 'sample.jpg'"

Comment: What entity is supposed to be calling the API service?  (A service-to-service call?  A browser application?)  How mechanically are you performing that call?

Comment: Apologies for skipping the basic introduction. The 'web' service is a React web application, the `api` service is a Django Rest Framework container service & the `db` is postgres. The web app is suppose to fetch some data to show once the app is initially loaded.

Comment: @Kayote what response do you get when you `telnet api 9000` or `curl http://api:9000` from the web container?

Comment: @runwuf I get a seemingly json response with the keyword & api address as value. I recognise the api. Thanks

Comment: Isn’t this a CORS issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it was a case of env variable not accessible within `web` service. All it took was to read the console logs in the browser which showed the `undefined` variable.

The lesson for me is to when it comes to problem solving, no matter how new the technology, don't forget to use the tools you are familiar with.

Comment: I'm glad you figured out the issue and resolved it! @Kayote